# JavaFX8: Problems with TreeView style

Tags: css, treeview, javafx-8

I have this wierd problem when trying to CSS style a TreeView.
This TreeView is Filterable to show only the items which I'm looking for.
This is how it looks when the Tree is shown without any filtering
[image]

And here's how it looks like, when there's a filtering active
[image]

I wanted to have all expanded nodes to have a colored background (green in this example).
So I added a Stylesheet containing the following code

```
.search-tree .tree-cell:expanded {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

But as you can see, the empty cells in the 2nd image are still colored even there's no content in it.
I also checked the component with ScenicView and indeed the pseudoClassState is still 'expanded'.
[image]

Does anyone have a idea why this empty cell is still in this state?

Here's the sample code that I used:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTest extends Application {
    TreeView<Object> t;
    private TextField searchField;
    private TreeViewHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {
        helper = new TreeViewHelper();
        t = new TreeView<>();
        t.getStyleClass().add("search-tree");
        TreeItem rootItem = new TreeItem("");

        TreeItem cars = new TreeItem("Cars");
        cars.getChildren().addAll(helper.getCars());
        cars.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem buses = new TreeItem("Buses");
        buses.getChildren().addAll(helper.getBuses());
        buses.setExpanded(true);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        rootItem.getChildren().add(cars);
        rootItem.getChildren().add(buses);
        t.setRoot(rootItem);
        t.setShowRoot(false);
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(t); 
        searchField = new TextField();
        searchField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> prop, String lastValue, String v) {

                scanItems();
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(searchField); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(new File("style.css").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
        s.setScene(scene);
        s.show();     
    }

    void scanItems()
    {
        t.getRoot().getChildren().clear();

        TreeItem cars = new TreeItem("Cars");
        helper.getCars().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchField.getText().toLowerCase()))
            .forEach(item -> cars.getChildren().add(item));
        t.getRoot().getChildren().add(cars);
        cars.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem buses = new TreeItem("Buses");
        helper.getBuses().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchField.getText().toLowerCase()))
            .forEach(item -> buses.getChildren().add(item));
        t.getRoot().getChildren().add(buses);
        buses.setExpanded(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch( args );
    }

    class TreeViewHelper 
    {
        public TreeViewHelper()
        {
        }

        // This method creates an ArrayList of TreeItems (Products)
        public ArrayList<TreeItem> getProducts()
        {
            ArrayList<TreeItem> products = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();

            TreeItem cars = new TreeItem("Cars");
            cars.getChildren().addAll(getCars());
            cars.setExpanded(true);

            TreeItem buses = new TreeItem("Buses");
            buses.getChildren().addAll(getBuses());
            buses.setExpanded(true);

            products.add(cars);
            products.add(buses);

            return products;
        }

        // This method creates an ArrayList of TreeItems (Cars)
        ArrayList<TreeItem> getCars()
        {
            ArrayList<TreeItem> cars = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();

            TreeItem ferrari = new TreeItem("Ferrari");
            TreeItem porsche = new TreeItem("Porsche");
            TreeItem ford = new TreeItem("Ford");
            TreeItem mercedes = new TreeItem("Mercedes");

            cars.add(ferrari);
            cars.add(porsche);
            cars.add(ford);
            cars.add(mercedes);

            return cars;        
        }

        // This method creates an ArrayList of TreeItems (Buses)
        ArrayList<TreeItem> getBuses()
        {
            ArrayList<TreeItem> buses = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();

            TreeItem gm = new TreeItem("GM");
            TreeItem vw = new TreeItem("VW");
            TreeItem man = new TreeItem("MAN");
            TreeItem volvo = new TreeItem("Volvo");

            buses.add(gm);
            buses.add(man);
            buses.add(volvo);
            buses.add(vw);

            return buses;       
        }

    }

}
```

Edit: I have this issue on MacOSX 10.11 using Java 1.8.0_77b3

Comment: I've seen similar issues with TableView's too..

Comment: I've tried your example with JavaFX8 and JavaFX2.2, in both it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.
By simply adding following style and defining the **empty** state

```
.search-tree .tree-cell:empty {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

it was working as expected.
[image]